# WP-e-commerce (getshopped) - Annoying permalink issue

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error, plugin-wp-e-commerce, plugin-wpml

i’m using wp-ecommerce (getshopped) and WPML on a website, all pages display correctly when i use the default (/ugly…) permalink structure, but when i try to use the much desired permalink structure /%category%/%postname%/ something weird happens:

1. product categories list page displays the homepage
2. single category and single product pages show the main blog page (list of post)

This prevents me from using my desired permalink structure, which is a major issue for me.

I tried updating WPEC to the latest beta version (didn’t help) and i tried switching to twenty ten to see if the problem is related to my theme (and it isn’t)

Questions:
1. Could this be related to the fact that i use hebrew words in my slugs?
2. Is there any known issues related to WPEC and permalinks that i should be aware of?
3. Can anyone point out the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this is, but i notices that different tables in my DB have different encoding - most are utf8_general_ci, some are latin1_swedish_ci, and some are hebrew_general_ci...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I find this a little bit a non-issue as it states clearly everywhere that WPML works 100% when you use a permalinks structure of day and name (http://domain.com/2012/02/07/sample-post/).

If this is something you cannot accept, then you's better come to terms with the fact that WPML most likely is not going to work 100% for you.

Or, to answer your questions:
re 1. no, this has nothing to do with the fact that you use Hebrew words in your slugs
re 2. no, there are no other known issues related to WPEC and permalinks that you should be aware of
re 3. the solution is to use a permalinks structure of day and name (http://domain.com/2012/02/07/sample-post/).